# Is there a way to check if kotlin class property was defined as nullable at runtime?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-null-safety, kotlin-reflect

I have the following simple class structure:

```
package qwerty

import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties

class UserSet(
    var user1: User,
    var user2: User? = null,
)

class User(
    var id: Long
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val type = UserSet::class
    type.declaredMemberProperties // ???
}
```

In `UserSet` the first user is non-null, while the second is nullable.
There definetly should be a way how to check if a property was defined as nullable at runtime having `KClass` object, but i don't have an idea how to do it.

I found `isMarkedNullable` in `outType` in `_descriptor` in idea evaluate window during debug, but i can't get access to it from my code.

So the question is how to check if properties of a class defined as nullable in runtime?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isMarkedNullable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/is-marked-nullable.html) on the property's type. Note that `isMarkedNullable` is a property of `KType`, not `KClass`. Whether or not you write `?`, it's the same `KClass`.

```
val type = UserSet::class
for (property in type.declaredMemberProperties) {
    println("${property.name} - ${property.returnType.isMarkedNullable}")
}
```

Output:

```
user1 - false
user2 - true
```